# How can I install BeautifulSoup in a Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, digital-ocean

I'm using the most basic service, running with Ubuntu (the standard config), I have developed some python scripts in my own PC that uses bs4, when I upload them it says the classical error:

`bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: xml. Do you need to install a parser library?`

So I try `pip install lxml`, and it asks that `libxml2` should be installed, and so on, and so on...

I'm not a Linux person, I'm more a Windows guy, I know maybe I have to compile something but I have no idea what or how. I've been looking for tutorials all noon, but I can't find nothing helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `ubuntu`, it's way easier to install the pre-packaged version using `apt-get install python-bs4`or `apt-get install python3-bs4`